# how to read a specific line which starts in "#" from file in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

how can i read a specific line which starts in "#" from file in python and 
set that line as a key in  a dictionary (without the "#") and set all the lines after that line until the next "#" as a value is the dictionary 
please help me
here is the file :

[image: 01]

Comment: first of all don't post image rather copy-paste it. Also show us how you have tried to solve this problem.

Comment: so how can i show the information of the file?

Comment: You can paste the file's data into your question and place it in a code block (by selecting the data and clicking the `{}` button) to preserve formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict

key = 'NOKEY'
d = defaultdict(list)

with open('thefile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            key = line.replace('#', '')
            continue
        d[key].append(line)
```

Your dictionary will have a list of lines under each key. All lines that come before the first line starting with `'#'` would be stored under the key `'NOKEY'`.

Comment: You may also want to strip leading & trailing whitespace from the key after removing the leading `#`, eg `key=key.strip()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of Python's [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = {}
key = ''

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    for k, g in groupby(f_input, key=lambda x: x[0] == '#'):
        if k:
            key = next(g).strip(' #\n')
        else:
            d[key] = ''.join(g)

print d
```

This would give you the following kind of output:

```
{'The Piper at the gates of dawn': '*Lucifer sam....\nsksdlkdfslkj\ndkdkfjoiupoeri\nlkdsjforinewonre\n', 'A Saucerful of Secrets': '*Let there be\nPeople heard him say'}
```

Tested using Python 2.7.9

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple version

```
filename = 'test'
results = {}
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    while (1):
        text = f.readline()
        if (text == ''):
            break
        elif (text[0] == "#"):
            key = text
            results[key] = ''
        else:
            results[key] += text
```

From (ignoring additional blank lines, a bi-product of the Answer formatting):

#The Piper at the gates of dawn

*Lucifer sam....

sksdlkdfslkj

dkdkfjoiupoeri

lkdsjforinewonre

# A Saucerful of Secrets

*Let there be

People heard him say

Produces:

{'#The Piper at the gates of dawn\n': '*Lucifer sam....\nsksdlkdfslkj\ndkdkfjoiupoeri\nlkdsjforinewonre\n', '# A Saucerful of Secrets \n': '*Let there be\nPeople heard him say\n'}